# Loading NORB Dataset for use with Keras Tensorflow in Python

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I am trying to do some work with the NORB dataset (http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~ylclab/data/norb-v1.0-small/) but I can't get it read from the binary files where the dataset is contained. Any body can help?

I tried `numpy.fromfile()` but it read the files a in wrong way.

Comment: Please edit your question and describe what you mean by "in wrong way". Ideally show what you expect vs what you get and a minimal example program.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had the same problem, since I had to work with that dataset and I discovered that it is distributed in a strange binary format.

For this purpose I made a **python wrapper** that you may find useful. You can find it [**here**](https://github.com/ndrplz/small_norb).

**Usage** is as simple as:

```
 dataset = SmallNORBDataset(dataset_root='small_norb_root')
```

where `small_norb_root` is the folder in which the dataset files have been downloaded and extracted. All the parsing stuff takes place in the initialization of the class and it is transparent to the user. Once initialized, you can find the data you need in: `dataset.data['train']` or `dataset.data['test']` respectively.

You can also **explore** the dataset with:

```
dataset.explore_random_examples(dataset_split='train')
```

If everything went well, the output should look like the following:

[image]